# button to both submit form and redirect in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So, I've been trying to make a login screen, and I need the button to be both able to submit the form and redirect the link after the button is pressed. this is a .jsx file

```
const LoginPage = (props) => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleEmailChange = (event) => setEmail(event.target.value);
  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => setPassword(event.target.value);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      props.onSubmit({ email, password });
  };

  const [svg, setSvg] = useState(EyeOff);
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setSvg(EyeOff);
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  };

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setSvg(EyeOn);
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  };

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(authData.token);

  const handleLoginSubmit = (credentials) => {
    if (email === authData.username && password === authData.password) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        <Navigate to ='/administrator/dashboard'/>
    
      
    } else {
      alert("Invalid credentials");
    }
  };

  return(
    <div className='loginModule'>
        <div className='loginLogoCircle'>
            <img src = {People} className='loginLogo'/>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <p className='loginText'>
            Login to your account
        </p>
        <p className='credentials'>
            Enter your credentials
        </p>
            <div className='inputView'>
                <img src = {Email} className='inputLogo'/>
                <input 
                    type='email' value={email} 
                    placeholder='example@prodigy-id.com' 
                    className='inputColUser' 
                    onChange={handleEmailChange}/>
            </div>
                <div className='inputView' style={{marginTop: 20}}>
                    <img src = {Lock} className='inputLogo'/>
                    <input 
                        type={passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'} 
                        value={password} 
                        placeholder='Type password..' 
                        className='inputColUserPass' 
                        onChange={handlePasswordChange}/>
                    <div>
                        {svg === EyeOn ? (
                            <img src = {EyeOn} onClick={handleClick} className='inputLogo'/>
                          ) : (
                            <img src = {EyeOff} onClick={handleClick2} className='inputLogo'/>
                          )}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <Checkbox/>
            <a href='/administrator/dashboard'>
                <button onClick={handleLoginSubmit} type='submit' className="loginButton">
                    <p>LOGIN</p>
                    <img src = {Continue} className='buttonLogo'/>
                </button>
            </a>
        </form>
        <p className='termsFont'> By continuing, you're confirming that you've read our Terms & Conditions and Cookie Policy</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have tried to change the location of the button to outside the form but it seems that it didn't submit what is inside the form after i passed the form inside the button.

Comment: Why don't you redirect the user on onSubmit callback?

Comment: try `useNavigate` hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `onSubmit` function at the parent, just await your api call and redirect after. You can use the `useNavigate` hook to redirect.

More or less, your parent component should have these code.

```
//import the useNavigate then use it like this
const navigate = useNavigate();

const onSubmit = async (loginCredentials) => {
  //assuming this is your api call, the async await will wait for it to finish
  const response = await fetch("http://yourapicall.com/login", { body: loginCredentials});
  console.log({ response });
  //this will navigate you
  navigate('/theurlyouwanttonavigate');
}
```